# Angular pick up an item within an array

Tags: javascript, angular, api

I'm using angular to manipulate a tmdb api, but I'm having trouble getting an item that is inside an array, could you help me?
the answer that the array returns to me is this:

```
{
    "id": 423108,
    "results": [{
        "id": "608177732da846006e382e45",
        "iso_639_1": "en",
        "iso_3166_1": "US",
        "key": "qc6jN1BcJi0",
        "name": "Official Trailer – Warner Bros. UK & Ireland",
        "site": "YouTube",
        "size": 1080,
        "type": "Trailer"
    }, {
        "id": "6081f2879e45860058f36147",
        "iso_639_1": "en",
        "iso_3166_1": "US",
        "key": "h9Q4zZS2v1k",
        "name": "Official Trailer",
        "site": "YouTube",
        "size": 1080,
        "type": "Trailer"
    }, {
        "id": "60a3f3d8cb75d1003f6cad3f",
        "iso_639_1": "en",
        "iso_3166_1": "US",
        "key": "6Eb1V9gJ5Z4",
        "name": "Chasing Evil Featurette",
        "site": "YouTube",
        "size": 1080,
        "type": "Featurette"
    }, {
        "id": "60a7f244e16e5a003f89fcfb",
        "iso_639_1": "en",
        "iso_3166_1": "US",
        "key": "4GjhydkUMrQ",
        "name": "The Conjuring: The Devil Made Me Do It - Demonic Possession Featurette - Warner Bros. UK",
        "site": "YouTube",
        "size": 1080,
        "type": "Featurette"
    }, {
        "id": "60b65a605c563400782c09c4",
        "iso_639_1": "en",
        "iso_3166_1": "US",
        "key": "5FEdg3FhiGc",
        "name": "Final Trailer – Warner Bros. UK & Ireland",
        "site": "YouTube",
        "size": 1080,
        "type": "Trailer"
    }, {
        "id": "60b6e54aefd3c20041e08f6b",
        "iso_639_1": "en",
        "iso_3166_1": "US",
        "key": "AB9mPsH2z1U",
        "name": "The Conjuring: The Devil Made Me Do It | 2021 | Clip: "
        Mitigating Circumstances " HD",
        "site": "YouTube",
        "size": 1080,
        "type": "Clip"
    }, {
        "id": "60b9622aabf8e2006fb33499",
        "iso_639_1": "en",
        "iso_3166_1": "US",
        "key": "tLFnRAzcaEc",
        "name": "Final Trailer",
        "site": "YouTube",
        "size": 1080,
        "type": "Trailer"
    }, {
        "id": "60be2d10960cde006d905ecf",
        "iso_639_1": "en",
        "iso_3166_1": "US",
        "key": "2V2MmKkddM0",
        "name": "The Conjuring: The Devil Made Me Do It - Teaser",
        "site": "YouTube",
        "size": 1080,
        "type": "Teaser"
    }]
}
```

And I want to get the "key" item. The idea is to get the key and then concatenate it with the youtube link to redirect to the trailer on youtube, or put the youtube player in the application. I'm currently doing it this way:

```
this.clientService.getVideoID(this.id).subscribe(data => this.video = date)
```

But I only have access to video.results, I can't give video.results.key

Comment: This is because results is an array of objects, so you would need to access via `video.results[i].key`, where `i` is the positional argument for the object within results you wish to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `filter()` function like so

`const myVideo = results.filter(item => item.id === "608177732da846006e382e45")[0]`

note that it will only work if the `id` is unique, `filter` returns an array filled with item that return true on the condition ( item.key === "608177732da846006e382e45"), and then we take the 1st one which is supposed to be the only one.

and then you can access `myVideo.key`

Obviously replace `"608177732da846006e382e45"` with whatever your input is

Answer (score 1):

it seems there is a problem in this JSON element because it contains "
[image]